Add constraint to maximise momentum in moveit
Is it possible to add constraint to trajectory planners in MoveIt to plan a trajectory such that it maximize momentum?
For example lets say I want a robotic arm to hit an object. In this case I would require a trajectory that maximizes the momentum(indirectly velocity as mass stays constant) at the end of the path.
